# C# Parse List of Names Separated by Newline

Tags: c#

I currently have a .txt of names like so:

```
Samuel Sam
Bobby Bob
Alexia Alex
Elizabeth Liz
```

All of these names are separated by newlines. Now, what I want to do is put these names into an array or list that can be manipulated (adding letters/words, removing letters and words, etc.). I currently want to do this so that I can choose any name in the array and pass it on to another function, but I can't figure out how.

Example: I load 5 names into the list/array. I then choose the 4th name and pass it on to another function.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Location\Names.txt");

foreach (string line in names)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
```

Comment: How would I put ithis into a class?

Comment: you should explain better your answer. It is not okay just post code without explanation. OP should understand what answers mean.